# How to express Root Mean Squared Error as a percentage?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I want to compare the result of my prediction with that of another person's prediction. In the article, the author says 'The relative percentage of root mean square (RMS%) was used to evaluate the performance'. This is what I want to compare my prediction with.

Currently I'm calculating the root mean square error. However, I don't understand how to express this as a percentage

This is how I calculate my root mean square error using Python

```
rmse = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_predict)
```

Comment: I don't know how you can compare with results of an unstated author in an unreferenced article if you don't know their definition, or expect us to work out from this description what was being done. But it's possible that they compared RMSE with the standard deviation of whatever was being predicted.

Comment: Which article is this from?